# Qual a forma de configurar o VI para autocompletar e formatar os arquivos de forma padronizada conforme cada linguagem?

Tags: formatação, autocompletar, editor-de-texto, vim

Eu já uso o VI a alguns anos, acho que uns 20 anos, na época ainda no XCO Unix e Xenix, porém nunca tomei a iniciativa de tornar meu ambiente totalmente parametrizado para programar em linguagens como C/C++, PHP e Java.

Gostaria de preparar meu VI para que tenha sucesso no uso destas linguagens, ainda me ocorre situações que preciso conectar em servidores remotos e recompilar programas, sendo assim necessário editar os arquivos de forma urgente e o VI é a melhor escolha para mim.

Qual a forma de configura-lo para autocompletar e formatar os arquivos de forma padronizada conforme cada linguagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe a possibilidade de autocompletar palavras já existentes no seu código a partir do `vim 7` . Você pode utilizar esta função utilizando a combinação `CTRL + n` .

Para autocompletar palavras reservadas de algumas linguagens já disponíveis, utilize os comandos abaixo (para php)

```
:set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

Ou adicione a linha abaixo no seu `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

Utilize `CTRL + x` , `CTRL + o` para autocompletar.

Se não me engano, não existe autocomplete para java e C++, então você terá que instalar um plugin a parte. Sugiro o `vjde` e o link a seguir para instalá-lo: http://blog.vinceliu.com/2007/08/vim-tips-for-java-3-use-omni-completion.html

Outra coisa que eu acho legal é indentação automática (`sw` é a quantidade de espaços em branco. adicione no `~/.vimrc`),

```
set sw=4
set autoindent
```

e os plugins `tabe` e `NERDTree`.

Answer (score 0):

Lhe recomendo usar o http://vim-bootstrap.com/ É uma verdadeira mão na roda na hora de começar. Para auto completar, eu recomento YCM (YouCompleteMe) https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe junto com https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips